# Cannot find source of Segmentation Break error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

We are supposed to code a recursive fibbonachi function using the stack as homework. Because I do not have any way to run NASM code directly on my laptop, I used browser based compilers such as jdoodle and coding ground to test if my code worked and debug. After an entire day of non-stop working, I cannot find why my code still does a segmentation fault error.

I have analysed the structure of the stack step by step, and cant find an error there. I might be missing something obvious, as I am still learning NASM and have not fully grasped some concepts. The error might also be within the online browser, or at least how it handles the output: I usually use printf, but I tried to repurpose the example code they provide.

For debug purposes, the value of R is entered with mov dword[R]. Also, since the output dosent use printf, it outputs the awnser as an ascii characther, where the ascii code of the characther is the outputted number.

```
section .text

global _start

fib:

    ;ret    <- esp
    ;R      
    ;ebps
    ;???    <- ebp?

    cmp dword[esp + 4], 4
    JS TroisOuMoins

    mov dword[ebx], esp
    add dword[ebx], 8
    push dword[ebx]

    ;ebps'  <- esp
    ;ret    
    ;R      
    ;ebps
    ;???    <- ebp?

    mov ebp, dword[esp]

    ;ebps'   <- esp
    ;ret
    ;R
    ;ebps   <- ebp

    sub dword[esp + 8], 1  ; R = R - 1
    push dword[esp + 8]

    ;R'     <- esp
    ;ebps'  
    ;ret
    ;R
    ;ebps   <- ebp

    call fib

    ;fib1    <- esp
    ;ebps'  
    ;ret
    ;R
    ;ebps   <- ebp

    push dword[esp]

    ;fib1   <- esp
    ;fib1    
    ;ebps'  
    ;ret
    ;R
    ;ebps   <- ebp

    mov ebx, dword[esp + 16]
    mov dword[esp + 4], ebx
    pop dword[esp + 16]
    dec dword[esp]

    ;R'     <- esp
    ;ebps'  
    ;ret
    ;fib1
    ;ebps   <- ebp

    call fib

    ;fib2   <- esp
    ;ebps'  
    ;ret
    ;fib1
    ;ebps   <- ebp

    mov ebx, dword[esp]
    add dword[esp + 12], ebx
    sub esp, 8

    ;ret    <- esp
    ;fibTotal
    ;ebps   <- ebp

    mov ebp, dword[ebp]

    ;ret    <-esp
    ;fibTotal
    ;ebps
    ;???    <-ebp?

    TroisOuMoins:

ret

_start:
    push ebp            ; --> 1 - sauvegarder l'état de la pile et du record d'activation présent (le contenu du ebp est mis sur la pile)
    mov ebp, esp            ; Mettre la valeur du "stack pointer" dans le "base pointer".


    mov dword[R], 4

    push ebp

    push dword[R]

    call fib

    pop dword[R]

    mov ebp, dword[esp]
    sub esp, 4

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp             ; <-- 1- restauration du ebp original

    mov     ebx, dword[R]
    mov     [sum], ebx

    mov     ecx, msg
    mov     edx, len
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80

    mov     ecx, sum
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80

    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80


section .data
    R:          times 4 db 0 ; 32-bits integer = 4 bytes
    msg db  "Fibbonachi is "
    len equ $ - msg

segment .bss

    sum resb 1
```

The code works for cases 1, 2 and 3, as per design (the function skips over the recursive calls for cases 1, 2 and 3, so the problem probably lies within there.). Any number higher then 4 produces the error "segmentation fault". The expected result is the corresponding Fibbonachi number for the input.

Comment: `fib` attempts to access `[ebx]`, but you haven't initialized `ebx` by the time you call `fib`.

Comment: By the way, that `sub esp, 4` in your `_start` routine is pointless since you're giving `esp` a different value on the very next line.

Comment: Use registers to hold values you're working with; that's what they're for.  Did you intend to use `mov ebx, [esp+4]` to load the arg from the stack?